# Read large text files in C efficiently

Tags: c, io, large-data, large-files

I need to read large text files containing either real or complex data in C. As of right now, I am using the code shown below. These functions are simple to understand and work fine for small sizes. However, I need to read files that are a few GBs in size which is taking a lot of time in comparison to binary files with the same data. (The project switched from text to binary files at some point because of the larger sizes. I have to clean up the mess.)

```c
int io_read_array_real(char ordering, DTYPE *array,
                       int m, int n, FILE *ifile)
{
    int i, j, match;
    DTYPE elem;
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            match = fscanf(ifile, "%e", &elem);
            if (match == 0)
            {
                printf("An error occurred while parsing the file!\n");
                return (-1);
            }
            if (ordering == 'C')
                *(array + RTC(i, j, m)) = elem;
            else if (ordering == 'R')
                *(array + i * n + j) = elem;
            else
                return (-1);
        }
    }
    return (0);
}

int io_read_array_complex(char ordering, CDTYPE *array,
                          int m, int n, FILE *ifile)
{
    int i, j, info;
    DTYPE zreal, zimag;
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            info = fscanf(ifile, " (%e%ej) ", &zreal, &zimag);
            if (info != 2)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "Input file in wrong format at (%d,%d) info = %d!\n"
                                "strerror: %s\n",
                        i, j, info, strerror(errno));
                return (-1);
            }
            if (ordering == 'C')
                *(array + RTC(i, j, m)) = zreal + I * zimag;
            else if (ordering == 'R')
                *(array + i * n + j) = zreal + I * zimag;
            else
                return (-1);
        }
    }
    return (0);
}
```

Now I'd like to know if there's any faster way of reading these files. They are guaranteed to be of the form:

```
real:
1.233e-3 2.231e-1 ...
2.335e-4 8.241e-2 ...
.
.

complex:
(1.233e-3+3.239e-4j) (1.233e-3+3.239e-4j) ...
(7.684e-2+8.269e-5j) (1.233e-3+3.239e-4j) ...
.
.
```

Comment: Parsing text takes time. There's a good reason to convert to binary when you can.

Comment: I don't see any way to significantly increase the performance for reading text files. Using binary files instead has the advantage that the data size is significantly smaller and that no conversion from text to binary is necessary. Therefore, I recommend that you store the data as binary if you want increased performance.

Comment: Side note: I recommend that you change `if(match == 0)` to `if(match != 1)`, because if `fscanf` returns `EOF` for some reason, your program will incorrectly interpret this as the function being successful.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel, I have switched to binary for further work, this question arose while doing the conversion to binary. Also I will look into your side note, though I feel that an error will arise anyway except when exactly the last number is missing.

Comment: Side note: `*(array + RTC(i, j, m))` can be written as `array[RTC(i, j, m)]`. This won't increase performance, but may increase code clarity.

Comment: How fixed is the data? Can you be absolutely positive it is one digit, a decimal point, three digits, “e”, a sign, and one digit? You could read the data as strings of fixed length and then process the characters with specialized code that avoids the general floating-point parsing.

Comment: Does the file have to use that format? Can you change to hexadecimal floating-point instead of decimal?

Comment: You can change the loop to do `n-1` iterations and ignore the `fscanf` return value in each. Then add a final `fscanf` where you check the return value.

Comment: Do not do arithmetic to construction complex numbers (`zreal + I*zimag`). Read directly into the real and imaginary parts in memory.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: The way I read it the text files are a legacy format and the present code is used to convert to binary, so the format seems to be fixed. The precision in the text files seems to be limited, and I like your idea of a custom parsing function.

Comment: In each routine, move the test of `ordering` outside the loop; do a test in the main code of the routine to select between a loop for the C case, a loop for the R case, or a return of −1.

Comment: Read and parse in different threads?

Comment: Have you profiled the processing of these files?  If the bottleneck is the IO, all the optimization of the code won't help a bit.

Answer (score 2):

You might memory map the entire file. The file content is then memory addressable directly and the operating-system's virtual memory management handles the memory and paging for you regardless of the size of the file.

You then operate on the file content directly as if it were memory - no explicit allocation, reallocation.

Windows and POSIX API's for memory mapped files differ, but you will find plenty of examples for whatever system you are using.

The advantage here is that the OS will manage loading data into the virtual address space in the background and the performance is likely to be determined by the amount of physical memory available.  Moreover it will load and page large chunks of the file at once which is fare more efficient than reading the file stream 23 bytes at a time.

If you do persist with stream I/O, you would do well at least to reduce the file I/O overhead by reading in larger "*power if two*" sized blocks, such as 1024 or 4096 bytes.

Comment: And reading in exponentially larger chunks if you do not know in advance how big the file is. First read is of size 1024, then 2048, then 4096 etc.

Comment: @SophiaKoulen : you could do that.  There is no reason though why you couldn't know the size of the file, or attempt to read more data than remains in the file. Ideally you would read in as large a chunk as you can given memory available, but, then you may as well be using a memory mapped file in any case - too large a chunk and it may juse end up in the swap file in any case.  With stream I/O though you are likely to get diminishing returns from ever larger chunks as the I/O overhead is a smaller proportion of the overall processing.

Answer (score 1):

There are **small** improvements possible:

- Move repetitive `if (ordering == 'C')` outside the loops and have it select one of two similar block to iterate.
- Move most of destination address calculation outside the innermost loop so `fscanf()` can save directly into the target destination.

But for **significant** improvements, OP is limited unless code can make assumptions about the format of the text representing floating point values and replace `fscanf()`. [@Eric Postpischil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75419572/read-large-text-files-in-c-efficiently/75420757#comment133075135_75419572)

Example:

If complex data is `(#.###e@#+#.###e@#j)`  (`#` digit, `@` sign), it **may** be faster to craft code.

Following is illustrative.  The exact details depend on the *precise* definition of OP's data format.  OP should profile various approaches.

```
// fscanf(ifile, " (%e%ej) ", &zreal, &zimag);
// (#.###e@#@#.###e@#j)
//  123456789 123456789 1
char buf[21+1+1]; // Input length + \n + \0
buf[19] = 0;
if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, ifile)) {
  if (buf[19]!=')') Error_out; // trivial error check
  static const double expos[19] = { 1.0e-12, 1.0e-11, ..., 1.0e+6}; // Offset by 3: #.###
  int e = buf[7]=='-' ?  buf[8]-'0' : -(buf[8]-'0');
  *dest++ = (buf[1]*1000 + buf[3]*100 + buf[4]*10 + buf[5] - 1111*'0') * expos[e+9];
  ...
```

- Multiple threads? [@Martin James](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75419572/read-large-text-files-in-c-efficiently/75420757#comment133076315_75419572) is a worthy idea to test.

Comment: `int e = buf[7]=='-' ?  buf[8]-'0' : -(buf[8]-'0');` can be replaced with branchless code: `int e = (1 - 2 * (buf[7] == '-')) * (buf[8] - '0');`  This expression can be simplified if the exponent array is extended and reordered: `int index = 10 * (buf[7] == '-') + (buf[8] - '0');`

Comment: Using `float` arithmetics might yield marginal improvements if the target structures use `float` values.